# A pointer to pointer in a struct C/ObjC

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, struct, syntax-error

```
typedef struct {  
    float Position[3];  
    float Color[4];  
    float VertexNormal[3];  
} Vertex;  

typedef struct WingedEdge{  
    struct WingedEdge* sym;  
    struct WingedEdge* next;  
    struct WingedEdge* prev;  
    Vertex** vertex;  
    GLushort** indexPointer;  
} WingedEdge;  

Vertex* vertices;  
GLushort* indices;  
struct WingedEdge* wingedEdges;  
int numberOfVertices; //initialized elsewhere
int numberOfIndices; //initialized elsewhere,this is multiplied by three since I am not using a struct for the indices
vertices = (Vertex *) malloc(numberOfVertices * sizeof(Vertex));
indices = (GLushort *) malloc(numberOfIndices * sizeof(GLushort) * 3);

wingedEdges = (struct WingedEdge*)malloc(sizeof(struct WingedEdge)*numberOfIndices*3);  
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIndices*3; i+=3) {  
    wingedEdges[i].indexPointer = (&indices+i);  
    wingedEdges[i+1].indexPointer = (&indices+i);  
    wingedEdges[i+2].indexPointer = (&indices+i);  

    wingedEdges[i].vertex = (&vertices+indices[i]);
    wingedEdges[i+1].vertex = (&vertices+indices[i+1]);
    wingedEdges[i+2].vertex = (&vertices+indices[i+2]);

    NSLog(@"%hu %hu %hu", *(indices+i),*(indices+i+1),indices[i+2]); 
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f", (vertices+indices[i])->Position[0], (vertices+indices[i])->Position[1], (vertices+indices[i])->Position[2]);
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f", (vertices+indices[i+1])->Position[0], (vertices+indices[i+1])->Position[1], (vertices+indices[i+1])->Position[2]);
    NSLog(@"%f %f %f", (vertices+indices[i+2])->Position[0], (vertices+indices[i+2])->Position[1], (vertices+indices[i+2])->Position[2]);

    NSLog(@"%hu", **(wingedEdges[i].indexPointer));  
}
```

Tried looking at a few other problems with pointers and structs but I did not find anything. I am getting an error with the last NSLog call. Everything thing in the NSLog calls with indices and vertices is correct so it looks like it might be a simple syntax error or pointer issue. Also, how would I increment the pointer that indexPointer points to? Since indexPointer points to a indices pointer, then I want to access indices+1 and indices+2 as well through indexPointer.

Comment: where is the variable indices initialization code ?

Comment: I added it, can't put everything in here or it would be massive, but all the code relating to wingedEdges should be here.

Comment: In case you are wondering why I use a pointer to a pointer, it's just in case the values are changed in vertices or indices, that way I don't have to change the values in wingedEdge again.

Comment: Small technicality... this should be called halfEdge since it only contains the origin vertex... anyway, not that important.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, if I comment that line out and let it fill the entire array of structs I have no problems.

Comment: Have you tried `wingedEdges[i].indexPointer = &(indices+i);` or `wingedEdges[i].indexPointer = &indices[i];` instead?

Comment: Neither work... I guess the question is why does &(indices+i) not work in Xcode...

Answer (score 0):

(&indices+i) doesn't point to any memory you have allocated.

What will work is to change the indexPointer and vertex to single pointers and then

```
wingedEdges[i].indexPointer = &indices[i];
wingedEdges[i].vertex = &vertices[indices[i]];
```

Then *(wingedEdges[i].indexPointer) is the same as indices[i] and
wingedEdges[i].vertex->Position[0] is the same as vertices[indices[i]].Position[0].  However, you will not get the automatic updating that you want (see my comments for more details).   I recommend a simple inline function:

```
inline *Vertex vertex(WingedEdge* e) 
{
    return &vertices[*(e->indexPointer)];
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't like that: Address expression must be an Ivalue or a function designator (Xcode)

Comment: But I think you are on the right track because if I just go (&indices) then there is no error, however, that's not that value I want, need to offset it.

Comment: @MCH: How about `&indices[i]`?

Comment: Doesn't work: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'GLushort **' from 'GLushort *'

Comment: Please try edits above.  Note that I think you really want single pointers.

Comment: I understand that single pointers would be easier, but my reasoning is if the values in indices or vertices changes for some reason, then I don't need to change the values in wingedEdges again. If I can't find a good solution then I will use single pointers.

Comment: @MCH what you have to worry about are only if the index values change, for then vertices[indices[i]] will not be the same as wingedEdges[i].vertex.  However, you cannot automatically update via double dereferencing just by changing the indices array values.  Suppose v was a Vertex**.  Then **v isn't going to change value without updating the pointer address contained in *v.  Since *v can't be pointer to a value in indices, you can't change it by changing indices.  I recommend a simple inline function: inline *Vertex vertex(WingedEdge* e) {return &vertices[*(e->indexPointer)]}.